# One-to-many relationship update existing values

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using Hibernate with JPA annotations. I'm using the following code to update entities in a one-to-many relationship. Here, one challenge can have many goals. I get all the existing goals and try to update all values but it's not getting saved in the database. However, if I add new goals, then those are getting persisted without any issues.
I'm not seeing any errors or exceptions.
Is it not the right way to update a list and persist in DB using Hibernate?

```
final Challenge challenge = findChallengeById(challengeId);

challenge.getGoals().forEach(goal -> {
    goal.setGoalValue(200);  //This change is not getting updated in database.
});

challenge.getGoals().addAll(newGoals);  //This gets persisted in database.

getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(challenge);
getCurrentSession().flush();
```

A one-to-many relationship:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "challenge", targetEntity = ChallengeGoalImpl.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@Override
public List<ChallengeGoal> getGoals() {
    return goals;
}
```

Bidirectional relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = ChallengeImpl.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "challenge_id")
@Override
public Challenge getChallenge() {
    return challenge;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my first look it should be added property in annotation fetch= FetchType.EAGER In this case your goals will extract from db  with findChallengeById(challengeId). Simply use DEBUGGER to see your data from db

Comment: Setting the fetch type to `EAGER` didn't make any difference.